# Manual calculation of ARIMA(2,1,1) forecast

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to calculate manual forecast of dataset using python generated ARIMA(2,1,1) coefficients for small testing dataset that contain 10 points.
Python gives me

```
AR1 -1.293,  
AR2 -0.901, 
MA1 0.9998, and 
sigma 174.936.
```

Without constant.

So, forecasting for 1 period should be
yt = series[9] + ar1*(series[9]-series[8]) + ar2*(series[8]-series[7])+MA1 * forecast_error[9] = 2+(-1.293*(2-19))+(-0.901*(19-57))+0.9998*(-10.131) = 58.219 +(-10.129) = **48.09**.

However, python gives `me model_fit.forecast(1)` = **49.30**

How this difference can be explained? What is the right way to calculate forecast? The same error happens with ARIMA(3,1,1) but models where q=0 calculates correctly by this method. I'm using formula from [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360164/i-computed-arma-equation-from-r-manually-but-never-got-the-same-result-with-pred/360233#360233).

Thank you.

Code

```
from pandas import read_csv
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

series = read_csv('2.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0).squeeze("columns")

p,d,q = 2,1,1
model = ARIMA(series, order=(p,d,q))
model_fit = model.fit()
const = 0
python_forecast = model_fit.forecast(1)
ar1, ar2 = model_fit.params.values[0], model_fit.params.values[1]
#do AR part
my_forecast = const + series[-1] + ar1*(series[-1]-series[-2]) + ar2*(series[-2]-series[-3])
#do MA part
my_forecast = my_forecast - model_fit.forecasts_error[0][9]*-model_fit.params.values[-2]
print(python_forecast[0], my_forecast)
```

Dataset 2.csv:

```
Month, sales
2019-01-17,14
2019-01-18,11
2019-01-19,50
2019-01-20,5
2019-01-21,12
2019-01-22,28
2019-01-23,10
2019-01-24,57
2019-01-25,19
2019-01-26,2
```

Comment: I think rounding the numbers to 2-3 decimals would make the post easier to read.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you, i fixed this post

Comment: Can you provide your full reproducible code?

Comment: @StephanKolassa sure, done